# Move row to next tab

Tags: excel, newline, vba

I have been trying to move my "completed" items from one tab to the next. I have succeeded in having them move over. However, they are going to my 2nd row (below my headers) and deleting what is there. How do I move it over and have it added to what is already there, instead of deleting the row and taking its place? This is the code that I am using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Column = 8 Then
  If Target = "Yes" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
      nxtRow = Sheets("ClosedProjects").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       Target.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("ClosedProjects").Range("A" & nxtRow)
       Target.EntireRow.Delete
  End If
 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: For the computation of `nxtRow` you are using column `I`, So you need to make sure that this column is the one that laways has data in the target worksheet. Otherwise, choose some column that verifies this property.

Comment: Is column I empty?  Maybe use `"H"` instead as this is the column you are testing and will definitely have a value.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I knew it had to be a simple mistake that I was making somewhere! I don't know how I got "i" instead of "H", but this fixed it!